# Given an $R$-module $M$, then $soc(M) = ann_M(J(R))$ if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, socle

Given an $R$-module $M$:

1. $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$.
2. Given $X \subset R$,  $ann_M(X) = \{m \in M: \forall r \in X, rm = 0\}$.
3. $Soc(M)$ is the socle of $M$ (the submodule of $M$ generated by all simple submodules of $M$).

The exercise ask to prove that $Soc(M) \subseteq ann_M(J(R))$ and that we have equality if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple.
I was able to prove $Soc(M) \subseteq ann_M(J(R))$ but I am completely clueless on how to prove the other direction. What I tried so far without success:

1. Proving that $ann_M(J(R))$ is a semisimple module
2. For any $m \in ann_M(J(R)$, $\langle m\rangle$ is a simple module.

Any tips on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley R is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: @rschwieb I've never seen a result showing that $J(R)$ will annihilate simple $R$ modules could you please reference some material or post a proof in the answers of this fact?

Comment: @DiogoSantos It's in the first sentence of [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) for example.   And every algebra book I've read...  Quite often that is the first definition of it.  It's very easy to see the connection between "intersection of all maximal right ideals" and "annihilates $R/M$ for every maximal right ideal."

Comment: @rschwieb I'm sorry I copied the problem with mistakes (the iclusions were reversed) it's fixed now, this was a problem from my normal season exam of algebra.

Comment: @DiogoSantos OK, glad to have the inclusion mistake sorted out.